# Pyinstaller is unable to run a Kivy Application due to KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm packaging a Kivy Application using pyinstaller.  The original application works fine, but when running from the dist folder, it fails due to a key error.  Specifically, it starts the Kivy application, but then immediately closes due to the key error.

Error Message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'screen_login'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "cli.py", line 5, in <module>
   File "kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
   File "kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
   File "src\__main__.py", line 26, in build
   File "src\__main__.py", line 20, in __init__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

The main.py with the resource_path function added.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import os
import sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path, resource_find


# Import files like
from CheckIn_Application.src.screens.login.login import LoginScreen
from CheckIn_Application.src.screens.checkin.checkin import CheckInScreen


def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


# Make all stuff modular
class WindowManager(BoxLayout):
    # Class Widgets
    login_widget = LoginScreen()
    check_in_widget = CheckInScreen()

    print(resource_path('maincheckin.kv'))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # super(WindowManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Add Widget
        self.ids.screen_login.add_widget(self.login_widget)
        self.ids.screen_checkin.add_widget(self.check_in_widget)


class MainCheckin(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Main().run()
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    MainCheckin().run()
```

And the associated .kv file

```
<WindowManager>:
    id: main_window

    ScreenManager:
        id: scrn_mngr_main

        Screen:
            id: screen_login
            name:'screen_login'
        Screen:
            id: screen_checkin
            name:'screen_checkin'
```

I think it has something to do with how pyinstaller interacts with the .kv file.  I can replicate this error when I change the Screen's id to a string (ie. id: "screen_login versus id: screen_login) in the original code.  I think Kivy makes it a point to not have their element id's identified as strings.

**EDIT:**
Spec File:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

from pathlib import Path
from pylibdmtx import pylibdmtx
from pyzbar import pyzbar

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
             ['cli.py'],
             pathex=['C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/DBlytics/CheckIn_Application'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/DBlytics/CheckIn_Application/src/maincheckin.kv','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

# dylibs are not detected because loaded by ctypes.
# binaries accept the TOC format.  Use list comprehension.
a.binaries += TOC([
    (Path(dep._name).name, dep._name, 'BINARY')
    for dep in pylibdmtx.EXTERNAL_DEPENDENCIES + pyzbar.EXTERNAL_DEPENDENCIES
])

# A dependency of libzbar.dylib that PyInstaller does not detect
MISSING_DYLIBS = (
    Path('/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib'),
)
a.binaries += TOC([
    (lib.name, str(lib.resolve()), 'BINARY') for lib in MISSING_DYLIBS
])


pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('maincheckin.kv', 'C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/DBlytics/CheckIn_Application/src/maincheckin.kv', 'DATA')]

exe = EXE(
          pyz,
          a.scripts,
          # *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='cli',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='cli')
```

When adding the .kv file to the spec in this method, I notice that pyinstaller adds the .kv file to dist\cli\ folder and not to to the _MEIPASS temp folder.

The issue is that I have the code correct in the original, but somehow after I package it, this error gets thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u share your .spec file with me?
I had the same problem a couple of weeks ago. I think that you didn't specify your data source.

My .spec file is located in: ../denul2/
My code files (.py/.kv) are located in: ../denul2/project/

Look at this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxpJf.jpg

edit:
Try to also add this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWQDM.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your input @Lennert Antson, I added the .spec file and the modified .py file which now includes the resource_path function.  What is interesting is that it shows the .kv file being added to the dist\cli folder as opposed to the _MEIPASS folder.  I agree that it's some kind of error in the .spec file.

Comment: Does the error still appear? How do you include your .kv file? If it still doesn't work maybe you should try to add the .kv like this: https://imgur.com/a/Dx1odJT

Comment: These were basically all the options I tried when I tried making the executable

Comment: Something interesting occurred.  Ultimately, your solution (via imgur.com/a/Dx1odJT ) works.  When I run it locally, it still works, but the system thinks it is getting two .kv files for login.  This results in a page with vertical divs, one is empty and one has the .kv features.  This is out of scope of my original question, so I may put it in another question.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add something.  So when i run it through the executable (via the dist folder pyinstaller created), it works completely fine, no odd div sections.